# Winston logger setting the timestamp of the log to 12/31/1969 instead of current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, logging, winston

I'm setting up logging in an app with winston and occassionally when I run tests a separate file is created with the date 12/31/1969. Is there something explicit I need to put in the creation of the transport so that it knows what the current date is?

What's very interesting is this seems to be a system wide anomaly as the `_log` method, which doesn't use the `new Date()` syntax, but the moment.js library also results in a 12-31-1969 inside the log file:
[image]

My logger:

```
class Logger{
  constructor(configs){
    if (!configs) configs = {};
    this.logDirectory = configs.directory ? path.join(__dirname, configs.directory) : path.join(__dirname, '../logs') ;
    this.initialize();
    this.date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  }

  initialize() {
    this._createTransportObj();
    this._createLoggerObj();
  }


  _createTransportObj() {
    const DailyRotateFile = winston.transports.DailyRotateFile;
    this._transport = new DailyRotateFile({
      filename: path.join(this.logDirectory, '/log-%DATE%.log'),
      datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      level: 'info'
    });
  }

  _createLoggerObj() {
    this._logger = winston.createLogger({
      level: 'info',
      format: winston.format.json(),
      transports: [this._transport],
      exitOnError: true
    });

    if (nodeEnv !== 'production') {
      this._logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
        format: winston.format.simple()
      }));
    }
  }

  _log(type, msg, options) {
    const logMsg = {};

    const timestamp = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    logMsg.level = type || 'info';
    logMsg.time = timestamp;
    logMsg.msg = msg || '';
    logMsg.desc = options.description || '';

    // get the user that made the request if available
    if (options.user) logMsg.user = options.user;

    // get the url endpoint that was hit if available
    if (options.url) logMsg.url = options.url;

    // if an error is sent through, get the stack
    // and remove it from msg for readability
    if (msg.stack) {
      logMsg.stack = msg.stack;
      msg = msg.message ? msg.message : msg;
    }

    // get the ip address of the caller if available
    if (options.ip) logMsg.ip = options.ip;

    // get the body of the request if available
    if (options.body) logMsg.body = options.body;

    // get the query string of the request if available
    if (options.query) logMsg.query = options.query;

    // get the params string of the request if available
    if (options.params) logMsg.params = options.params;

    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(logMsg);
    this._logger.log(type, logMsg);
  }

  info(msg, options) {
    return this._log('info', msg, options);
  }

  error(msg, options) {
    return this._log('error', msg, options);
  }

  warn(msg, options) {
    return this._log('warn', msg, options);
  }

  verbose(msg, options) {
    return this._log('verbose', msg, options);
  }

  debug(msg, options) {
    return this._log('debug', msg, options);
  }

  silly(msg, options) {
    return this._log('silly', msg, options);
  }
}

module.exports = { Logger };
```

I'm currently only testing it in a promise handler that my routes flow through:

```
const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  const logger = new Logger();
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .then(result => {
          if (req.body.password) delete req.body.password;
          logger.info(result,
              { user: req.user.username,
                url: req.originalUrl,
                body: req.body,
                description: '200:OK Response sent back successfully'
              });
          return res.status(200).json({ result })
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            return res.status(400).json({ error: e.message })
        });
};

module.exports = asyncHandler;
```

UPDATE*
ok, so it seems to not be the logger itself. I ran a batch of tests and noticed it's always the same route that triggers the date change. What's weird is I can't seem to figure out what's happening.

The route is:
[image]

and the `app.use()` statement is as follows:
[image]

finally the admin_access middleware is simple enought:
[image]

I've figured out if I break the endpoint in the `app.js` file before it hits `admin_access` the date is correct. However if I break in `admin_access` the date is 12-31-1969. So what could be happening between the two? Is there something I could be setting unintentionally on this route?

Comment: That is the day before the ECMAScript epoch of 1970-01-01, so perhaps you are creating a date with a time value of 0, something like `new Date(0)` where your system is set for a timezone with a negative offset (e.g. -04:00). That will occur if you do something like `new Date('1970-01-01')` then use local values to print a timestamp.

Comment: @RobG I am not setting the date anywhere though, that is what confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out the package sinon-test was changing the system time.

I had my test setup like this:

```
const sinon     = require('sinon');
const sinonTest = require('sinon-test');
const test     = sinonTest(sinon);
describe('Test suite for route: /video/admin/create', ()=>{
  let agent;

  beforeEach(async function() {
    // create temporary admin
    admin.permissionId = 1;
    await new NewUser().createUser(admin);

    //login as admin
    agent = chai.request.agent(server);
    await agent
        .post('/auth')
        .send({ username: admin.username, password: admin.password });
  });

  afterEach(async function() {
    // destroy temp admin
    await new UserManager(admin).hardRemove();
  });
  it('should fail to create a video for not including video info', test(async function(){
    const newVideo = { title: 'Test Video' };
    const response = await agent.post('/video/admin/create')
        .send(newVideo);

    expect(response.status).to.equal(400);
  }));

  it('should create a video', test(async function(){
    const newVideo = {
      title: 'Test Video',
      description: 'This is a description',
      embed: 'https://youtu.be/SKbHjjZXdmc',
      source: 'youtube',
      type: 'lecture',
      category: 'physics'
    };
    const response = await agent.post('/video/admin/create')
        .send(newVideo);

    // validations
    expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
    const { result } = response.body;
    expect(result.title).to.equal(newVideo.title);
    expect(result.description).to.equal(newVideo.description);
    expect(result.embed).to.equal(newVideo.embed);
  }));
});
```

When I unwrapped the test from the `test()` function everything worked correctly.